# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The current status of the connection is Open

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is the code I use:

```
  StringBuilder cmdTekst = new StringBuilder();
  SqlCommand cmd;
  cmd = Cnn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.Connection = Cnn;
  if (Cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    Cnn.Open();
  }
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmdTekst.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM tblNummering WHERE type = 1 AND EindPer IS NULL;");
  cmd.CommandText = cmdTekst.ToString();
  Log.Debug("sql tekst = '" + cmd.CommandText + "'");
  SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The code is simplified.

This is the exception I get

"ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The current status of the connection is Open."

As far as I know the connection is available and open.

I can not switch to use using. That would take several days of refactoring.

Several other connections are open before this one.
Setting the number of connection higher does not solve the problem.

Anyone a clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: I would challenge your presumption that it would take several days of refactoring to switch to a using-block.  Just refactor code when you come across it or like now, when you get exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

`... and available Connection` <= that is also important. Just because it is open does not mean it is not already being used by another thread (for example). The solution is to not reuse database connections, these types should be short lived. Created them as needed and dispose of them as soon as you are done. The underlying framework will handle connection pooling  for you so there is no benefit to trying to do it for the application.

If you can't dispose of the global connection then create a new one when you experience race conditions like this.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Cnn.ConnectionString)) // use same connection string as your Global instance
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblNummering WHERE type = 1 AND EindPer IS NULL;"
  connection.Open();
  using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while(reader.Read())
    {
      // fetch results
    }
  }
}
```